# How to attach error in invocation completion with SignalR?

Tags: .net, signalr

I have a SignalR implementation in .NET with a custom `IHubProtocol` that simply utilizes `JsonHubProtocol`.

I noticed that my SignalR server sends a message of type `CompletionMessage` along with the invocation ID, as well as other useful properties such as `Error` to indicate if there was an error, and also `HasResult`.

How can I "throw" an error when the invocation happens, so that the `Error` property will contain this error, so the client can handle it properly?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-6.0#handle-errors

Comment: @Brennan Thanks, however after trying to throw a new `HubException` from within my hub method, it still attempts to send a message of type `Completion` with `Error` being `null`. I then tried to configure the server to enable detailed errors ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options)), however that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial an error, I found out that my `LogFilter` which logs all my invocations was also catching all exceptions and logging them as errors, which prevented the SignalR error propagating mechanism from working properly. To fix this, I re-threw the exception after catching and logging.

That finally gave me client errors. However, I still didn't know what errors they were. To solve this, you have to enable an option to provide detailed errors when adding SignalR to your application services like so:

```
services.AddSignalR(o =>
            {
                // Provide detailed error messages only for non-production environments.
                o.EnableDetailedErrors = !HostEnvironment.IsProduction();
            });
```

The difference between detailed errors and non-detailed errors -- and this part is not *properly* documented anywhere -- is that a detailed error will give you the exception type and message.

Comment: You should be throwing a `HubException` instead. This setting is dangerous and could leak information about *any* exception throw.

Comment: @davidfowl this is why I’m only enabling it in non-production environments. As Microsoft said, HubException is not a good practice.

Comment: I am Microsoft... :)

Comment: @davidfowl So what's the problem with enabling detailed errors in non-production environments?

Comment: If you're confident its fine for your application scenario then 